# How to rotate an Arc2d object without passing a Graphics2d object reference

Tags: java, graphics2d

I am currently animating a Java game with a basic game loop. I have an Arc2d and a Line2d object arranged to look like a bow. I do not have a Graphics2d reference to utilize the rotate() method, but I need to rotate the Arc2d object and Line2d object together so that they continue to maintain the same shape and relation to each other, while following my mouse pointer.

I have tried modifying the start and extent parameters for the Arc2d object, but it failed to maintain its shape, and obviously moved in relation to the Line2d object. I have also tried to figure out a way to utilize the Graphics2d.rotate() method, but I don't see a way to pass a Graphics2d object to rotate.

This is the class I am trying to rotate the object in.

```
import controller.Main;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.Arc2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;

public class Shooter extends GameFigure {

    public final int BOW_STRING_SIZE = 40;
    public final int ARROW_LEN = 30;
    public final int UNIT_MOVE = 10;
    public Arc2D.Float bow;
    public Line2D.Float arrow;
    public Color color = Color.YELLOW;
    public double rad;

    public Shooter(int x, int y) {
        super(x, y);
        bow = new Arc2D.Float(x - BOW_STRING_SIZE / 2, y - 15, BOW_STRING_SIZE, BOW_STRING_SIZE, 0, 180, Arc2D.CHORD);
        arrow = new Line2D.Float(x, y, x, y - ARROW_LEN);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(Graphics2D g2) {
        g2.setColor(color);
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(7));
        g2.draw(arrow);
        g2.draw(bow);
    }

    @Override
    public void update() {
        MousePointer mousePointer = (MousePointer) Main.gameData.fixedObjects.get(Main.INDEX_MOUSE_POINTER);
        float tx = mousePointer.location.x;
        float ty = mousePointer.location.y;
        rad = Math.atan2(ty - super.location.y, tx - super.location.x);
        /*float barrel_y = (float) (ARROW_LEN * Math.sin(rad));
        float barrel_x = (float) (ARROW_LEN * Math.cos(rad));

        arrow.x1 = super.location.x;
        arrow.y1 = super.location.y;
        arrow.x2 = super.location.x + barrel_x;
        arrow.y2 = super.location.y + barrel_y;*/
    }
```

Currently, the arrow on the bow rotates with the mouse pointer, but the bow itself does not.

Comment: Combine the two shapes into an `Area` and rotate that - problem - you won't be able to paint them in different colours. Alternatively, you could use a [`AffineTransform#createTransformedShape`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#createTransformedShape(java.awt.Shape)) to create a new instance of the shape rotated as you need.  Problems here are trying to get the shape's translated and rotated about a common core

Comment: Alternatively, you could not just care about rotating the shape and instead, when it comes to paint it, apply the rotation at that point

Comment: @MadProgrammer I made the following modifications, but the arrow object isn't being drawn.

public Shooter(int x, int y) {
        super(x, y);
        bow = new Arc2D.Float(x - BOW_STRING_SIZE / 2, y - 15, BOW_STRING_SIZE, BOW_STRING_SIZE, 0, 180, Arc2D.CHORD);
        arrow = new Line2D.Float(x, y, x, y - ARROW_LEN);
        s1 = new Area(bow);
        s2 = new Area(arrow);
        sf = new Area();
        sf.add(s1);
        sf.add(s2);
    }